# NSFetchedResultsController fetchlimit update

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Hi I have implemented a UITableView with FetchedResultsController and its delegate methods. And I have set a fetch limit of 30 where users will click a more button, and it will load 30 more and all of that is working perfectly. But when an object, which is OUTSIDE of the loaded objects in the tableview is updated, the delegate methods aren't being fired.

What I intend to happen is for example I have loaded the first 30 objects and object 75 gets updated in which now it should be at the top of the table. Currently I just force a refetch when a user switches to another view and goes back. Can someone can give me pointers/help on this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Do you not want to set the batch size and remove the load more button?

Comment: Sorry but that is how we want the app to work, so no we cannot remove that, what is interesting though is that if the object is modified twice. Then the object appears on the top of the table view (assuming the object satisfies the sort descriptor that it will be on top).